# Unicode define statements in C preprocessor

Tags: c, preprocessor

I was doing some testing and fiddling about and noticed the C preprocessor does not let me use unicode with the define directive. Below is an example of my plight.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define φαντασία fancy

int main() {
        printf("Is the C preprocessor φαντασία?");
}
```

It is giving me this output...

```
$ ./a.out 
Is the C preprocessor φαντασία?
```

Is there some way to fix this behaviour, it seems worthy of a feature request perhaps. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Why did you expect a different output? You are not using the `#define`d macro anywhere

Comment: It's unrelated to unicode. The preprocessor does not look into strings: https://godbolt.org/z/8r9x7h56s You can do something like that: https://godbolt.org/z/zf8Mv5WKd

Comment: @mch That is interesting but how does it even know it is to be in a string there? If you know make an answer below and explain that because I am suddenly baffled.

Comment: Oh, the strings in the define?

Comment: Macros do not apply *within* strings.

Comment: Yeah, I did not notice the strings you added to the preprocessor statement, thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor replacement doesn't work on text; it works on *tokens*. When your `printf` line is processed, text is converted to 5 tokens first:

1. *identifier* token `printf`
2. *punctuator* token `(`
3. *string-literal* token `"Is the C preprocessor φαντασία?"`
4. *punctuator* token `)`
5. *punctuator* token `;`

Only *identifier* type tokens are considered by macro replacement system.